# Android status bar background gradient

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I need set my drawable(gradient) to status bar background(I need change only on status bar, not appbar).
I try:

```
<item name="statusBarBackground">@drawable/bg_gradient</item>
```

but not work.
this is my drawable:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <gradient
            android:type="linear"
            android:angle="90"
            android:startColor="#E4695E"
            android:endColor="#ffffff" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work on lollipop and above. Hope this helps!

-Use a style that doesn’t contain any ActionBar, like this one :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

-Or override the style you have, such as:

```
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

-In your activity’s onCreate method, add the following:

```
 @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStatusBarGradient(this); //add this
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
protected void setStatusBarGradient(Activity activity) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Window window = activity.getWindow();
            Drawable background = activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bg_gradient);
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(activity.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
            window.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
        }
    }
```